# Changing date to date-finding differences of time setting zero the changing(sometimes the difference may be positive)

Tags: r, date

I have this data set

```
date1<-c(rep(c("2020-06-01"),times=23))
date2<-c(rep(c("2020-06-06"),times=20))
date4<-c(rep(c("2020-06-11"),times=9))
date<-c(date1,date2,date4)
time<-c("05:55:14","06:25:14","06:55:14","07:25:14","07:55:14","08:25:14","08:55:14","09:25:14","09:55:14","10:25:14","10:55:14","11:25:14","11:55:14","12:25:14","12:55:14","13:25:14","13:55:14","14:25:14","14:55:14","15:25:14","15:55:14","16:25:14","16:55:14" ,"05:57:27","06:27:27","06:57:27","07:27:27","07:57:27","08:27:27","08:57:27","09:27:27","09:57:27","10:27:27" ,"10:57:27" ,"11:27:27","11:57:27","12:27:27","12:57:27","13:27:27","13:57:27","14:27:27","14:57:27","15:27:27","10:51:50","11:21:50","11:51:50","12:21:50","12:51:50","13:21:50","13:51:50","14:21:50","14:51:50")

data<-cbind(date,time)
date<-as.Date(date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
time<-as_hms(time)
```

I want the difference between times so i tried this

```
diff.time<- c(NA,`units<-`(diff(time),"secs"))
diff.time<-diff.time/60
data<-cbind(data,diff.time)
```

but at the output when changing date or a large range between times it happens this

```
   date         time       diff.time  
 [1,] "2020-06-01" "05:55:14" NA                 
 [2,] "2020-06-01" "06:25:14" "30"               
 [3,] "2020-06-01" "06:55:14" "30"               
 [4,] "2020-06-01" "07:25:14" "30"               
 [5,] "2020-06-01" "07:55:14" "30"               
 [6,] "2020-06-01" "08:25:14" "30"               
 [7,] "2020-06-01" "08:55:14" "30"               
 [8,] "2020-06-01" "09:25:14" "30"               
 [9,] "2020-06-01" "09:55:14" "30"               
 [10,] "2020-06-01" "10:25:14" "30"               
 [11,] "2020-06-01" "10:55:14" "30"               
 [12,] "2020-06-01" "11:25:14" "30"               
 [13,] "2020-06-01" "11:55:14" "30"               
 [14,] "2020-06-01" "12:25:14" "30"               
 [15,] "2020-06-01" "12:55:14" "30"               
 [16,] "2020-06-01" "13:25:14" "30"               
 [17,] "2020-06-01" "13:55:14" "30"               
 [18,] "2020-06-01" "14:25:14" "30"               
 [19,] "2020-06-01" "14:55:14" "30"               
 [20,] "2020-06-01" "15:25:14" "30"               
 [21,] "2020-06-01" "15:55:14" "30"               
 [22,] "2020-06-01" "16:25:14" "30"               
 [23,] "2020-06-01" "16:55:14" "30"               
 [24,] "2020-06-06" "05:57:27" "-657.783333333333"
 [25,] "2020-06-06" "06:27:27" "30"               
 [26,] "2020-06-06" "06:57:27" "30"               
 [27,] "2020-06-06" "07:27:27" "30"               
 [28,] "2020-06-06" "07:57:27" "30"               
 [29,] "2020-06-06" "08:27:27" "30"               
 [30,] "2020-06-06" "08:57:27" "30"               
 [31,] "2020-06-06" "09:27:27" "30"               
 [32,] "2020-06-06" "09:57:27" "30"               
 [33,] "2020-06-06" "10:27:27" "30"               
 [34,] "2020-06-06" "10:57:27" "30"               
 [35,] "2020-06-06" "11:27:27" "30"               
 [36,] "2020-06-06" "11:57:27" "30"               
 [37,] "2020-06-06" "12:27:27" "30"               
 [38,] "2020-06-06" "12:57:27" "30"               
 [39,] "2020-06-06" "13:27:27" "30"               
 [40,] "2020-06-06" "13:57:27" "30"               
 [41,] "2020-06-06" "14:27:27" "30"               
 [42,] "2020-06-06" "14:57:27" "30"               
 [43,] "2020-06-06" "15:27:27" "30"               
 [44,] "2020-06-11" "10:51:50" "-275.616666666667"
 [45,] "2020-06-11" "11:21:50" "30"               
 [46,] "2020-06-11" "11:51:50" "30"               
 [47,] "2020-06-11" "12:21:50" "30"               
 [48,] "2020-06-11" "12:51:50" "30"               
 [49,] "2020-06-11" "13:21:50" "30"               
 [50,] "2020-06-11" "13:51:50" "30"               
 [51,] "2020-06-11" "14:21:50" "30"               
 [52,] "2020-06-11" "14:51:50" "30"
```

How do I avoid having these large differences which means my data changes date or some how make my code recognize the changing of the date and set the first difference of this date as NA r zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

```
date1<-c(rep(c("2020-06-01"),times=23))
date2<-c(rep(c("2020-06-06"),times=20))
date4<-c(rep(c("2020-06-11"),times=9))
date<-c(date1,date2,date4)
time<-c("05:55:14","06:25:14","06:55:14","07:25:14","07:55:14","08:25:14","08:55:14","09:25:14","09:55:14","10:25:14","10:55:14","11:25:14","11:55:14","12:25:14","12:55:14","13:25:14","13:55:14","14:25:14","14:55:14","15:25:14","15:55:14","16:25:14","16:55:14" ,"05:57:27","06:27:27","06:57:27","07:27:27","07:57:27","08:27:27","08:57:27","09:27:27","09:57:27","10:27:27" ,"10:57:27" ,"11:27:27","11:57:27","12:27:27","12:57:27","13:27:27","13:57:27","14:27:27","14:57:27","15:27:27","10:51:50","11:21:50","11:51:50","12:21:50","12:51:50","13:21:50","13:51:50","14:21:50","14:51:50")

df<-data.frame(date = as.Date(date,format="%Y-%m-%d"),time = hms::as_hms(time))
```

#### Option 1: Base R

```
diff.time2 <- tapply(df$time, df$date, function(x) c(NA, diff(x)/60))
df$diff.time2 <- unlist(diff.time2)
```

#### Option 2: tidyverse

```
df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(diff.time.tidy=as.numeric(time-lag(time), units="mins"))
```